# Initial populating on Django Forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I decided to learn Django Forms. For a while now, I have been using HTML forms because it's hard for me to come to terms with Django Forms.

How could I populate initial data to Django Forms?
Example:

Consider if these models are populated. Contain data.

*models.py*

```
class Game(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField()
   genre = models.CharField()
```

so if I have

*view.py*

```
game_list = Game.objects.all()
return render_to_response('template',locals())
```

so in *template.html*, I could just:

```
{% for game in game_list %}
<p> game.title <p> <br /> <p> game.genre <p>
```

If I want to populate initial data when using *HTML forms*, this is what I usually do:

```
    {% for game in game_list %}
    <form action= '/add/' method='POST'>
    <input="text" name="title" value="{{game.title}}" />
    <input="text" name="genre" value="{{game.genre}}" />
    <input type="submit" />
```

How can I do this in Django Forms?
From what I've seen by reading articles online, they do this by overriding using `forms.__init__`:

```
class Anyforms(forms.Form):
   super(Anyforms, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
```

I can't get a hold of how to populate using `super`. What data do forms get during runtime and how?
Any good links that I could read to get me up and running on wrangling Django Forms?

Is this

```
<input="text" name="title" value="{{game.title}}" /> 
<input="text" name="genre" value="{{game.genre}}" />
```

equivalent to this?

```
data = {'title':'{{game.title}}','genre':'{{game.genre}}'} 
form(data)
```

Are the variables going to be replaced in template?

Comment: When you tried this, what did you observe?

Comment: "{{ game.title }}" in the fields. :(

Comment: In What fields?  Where?  What are you talking about?  Are you saying that your HTML page has NO data filled in?  If it has no data filled in, how did it get displayed?  What does your view function do?  If your view function does not use `render_to_response` you won't see any data filled in.  Please include your actual view function that is supposed to build and return this html page that includes the form.

Comment: Sorry lott, Ars answered that question. What i was doing is by
data={'title':'{{game.title}}'} and bind it to form(data) i was hoping in the template that the value['{{game.title}}'] in key['title'] is evaluated just like variable {{ game.title }}. 
Why is this? In python shell i ran print form(data), the html are the same as my html form <input="text" name="title" value="{{game.title}}" />. Now since im iterating on template using {% for game in game_title %} where game_title = Game.objects.all(), I was hoping it evaluate every data avail from the model.Sorry again for my vague question.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

S. Lott's answer tells you how to initialize the form with some data in your view.  To render your form in a template, see the following section of the django docs which contain a number of examples:

- [Outputting forms as HTML](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#outputting-forms-as-html)

Although the examples show the rendering working from a python interpreter, it's the same thing when performed in a template.

For example, instead of `print f`, your template would simply contain: `{{ f }}` assuming you pass your form through the context as `f`.  Similarly, `f.as_p()` is written in the template as `{{ f.as_p }}`.  This is described in the django template docs under the [Variables](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/#variables) section.

Update (responding to the comments)

Not exactly, the template notation is only for *template*.  Your form and associated data are initialized in the *view*.

So, using your example, your view would contain something like:

```
def view(request):
    game = Game.objects.get(id=1) # just an example
    data = {'id': game.id, 'position': game.position}
    form = UserQueueForm(initial=data)
    return render_to_response('my_template.html', {'form': form})
```

Then your template would have something like:

```
{{ form }}
```

Or if you wanted to customize the HTML yourself:

```
{{ form.title }} <br />
{{ form.genre }} <br />
```

and so on.

I recommend trying it and experimenting a little. Then ask a question if you encounter a problem.

Comment: data = {'id':'{{ game.id }}','position':'{{game.id}}'}
form = UserQueueForm(initial=data)
Are these gonna work?

Comment: <input="text" name="title" value="{{game.title}}" />
<input="text" name="genre" value="{{game.genre}}" />
are the same as this
data = {'title':'{{game.title}}','genre':'{{game.genre}}'}
form(data)

Is the variable gonna be replace in template?

Comment: @user459885: I updated the question to respond to your comments.

Comment: Thanks ars. So i had to initialize the value at view. In your example, it is for a single instance where Game.objects.get(id=1). 

What if im using Game.objects.all(). In the template im iterating on it using {% for game in Game.objects.all() %} then {{game.title}} {{game.position}}

if i were to use html form, i could just render every iterable objects by
 
<input="text" name="title" value="{{game.title}}" /> 
<input="text" name="genre" value="{{game.position}}" />

How could i achieve the same result using django forms?
Thank you for entertaining my dumb question. Appreciate it a lot.

Comment: @diehell: You want to use formsets.  I suggest you start with reading the docs on model formsets: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets -- if you encounter any problems, start a new question rather than continue in the comments here, to make it easier and keep things distinct.

Comment: If `UserQueueForm` is a `ModelForm`, you can initialize it with values from a model using the `instance=` argument: `form = UserQueueForm(instance=game)`. It saves you the trouble of creating a dictionary.

Answer (score 14):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/forms/api/#ref-forms-api-bound-unbound

To bind data to a form, pass the data as a dictionary as the first parameter to your Form class constructor:

```
>>> data = {'subject': 'hello',
...         'message': 'Hi there',
...         'sender': 'foo@example.com',
...         'cc_myself': True}
>>> f = ContactForm(data)
```

Comment: if the data isn't valid the user will be shown errors :(, but if you pass the data as the `initial` kwarg it will populate the fields with no errors `f = ContactForm(initial=data)`

Answer (score 12):

Do you could try the follow:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

def view(request):
    game = Game.objects.get(id=1)
    form = UserQueueForm(initial=model_to_dict(game))
    return render_to_response('my_template.html', {'form': form})
```

works fine for me on Django 1.8

Comment: this worked for me while fetching the get request.

Answer (score 6):

When using CBVs, you can override the [`get_initial()`](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.1/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/#get_initial) FormMixin to populate initial data into the form.

Example:

```
class MyView(FormView):

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(MyView, self).get_initial()
        initial['start_date'] = datetime.date.today()
        return initial
```

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_initial).

Answer (score 4):

just change

```
data = {'title':'{{game.title}}','genre':'{{game.genre}}'} 
form(data)
```

to

```
data = {'title':'{{game.title}}','genre':'{{game.genre}}'} 
form(initial=data)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the instance directly if you set the model attribute on the form class

```
class GameForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Game
```

In your view:

```
def view(request):
    game = Game.objects.get(id=1)
    form = GameForm(instance=game)
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'form': form})
```

Works for me on django 2.1

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work too, but not sure.

```
def view(request):
    game = Game.objects.get(id=1) # just an example
    form = UserQueueForm(instance=game)
    return render_to_response('my_template.html', {'form': form})
```

And in the view you can do like form.field to show form with intial data.

Comment: i had to change the object instance to dict using the `model_to_dict` function