# send arguments to django forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I want to pre-populate a textfield on a django form when the form is loaded. Below is my code.

I want this "content" field in forms.py to be pre-populated when my form loads in the browser. This field should be un-editable. But with the code below an empty textfield gets created.

I know I can pre-populate this info by sending it in the url string just like I am sending 'id'. But I don't want to take that approach. Is there any other way to send parameters to forms?

forms.py

```
class ContentModelForm(ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(max_length=256)
    message = forms.CharField(max_length=256)
    created_at = forms.DateTimeField('DateTime created')

    class Meta:
        model = Content

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContentModelForm, self).__init__()
        self.fields['content'].value = kwargs.get('content')
```

views.py

```
def post_form_upload(request, id):  
    post = get_object_or_404(models.Post, id=id)
    content = post.content 

    if request.method == 'GET': 
        form = ContentModelForm(content = content)
    else:
        form = ContentModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            created_at = form.cleaned_data['created_at']
            models.Content.objects.create(post_id = id,
                                        message = message,
                                        created_at = created_at)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post_form_upload',
                                          args = (post.next_id,))) 
    return render(request, 'survey_forms/post_form_upload.html',{
    'form':form,
     'id' : id,
    })
```

survey_forms/post_form_upload.html

```
<form action="{% url 'post_form_upload' id=id %}"  method='post'>
{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}
<input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
</form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why bother having a field at all if you want it to be prepopulated and readonly? Why not just display the value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initial populating on Django Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833403/initial-populating-on-django-forms)

Comment: @DanielRoseman I actually want to display the value. Can you suggest how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the [`initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) keyword argument when instantiating your form. This accepts a dictionary where the keys are the field name and the values are the initial values.

```
form = ContentModelForm(initial={'content': content})
```

Moreover since you want this field to be readonly. You should change this line

```
content = forms.CharField(max_length=256)
```

to

```
content = forms.CharField(max_length=256, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'})
```

Comment: doesn't work. I am still getting an empty TextField.

Answer (score 0):

if you want an input to be pre-populated then you might as well just give it a "value" attribute, for example.

```
input<type="text, value="content_you_want_in_there">
```