# Retrieving form data after setting initial value

Tags: python, django

I wanted to populate my form fields with initial data, so I've set my view just like recommended by @ars in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833403/initial-populating-on-django-forms):

```
def update_member(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        urn = 'urn:publicid:myurn'
        member = Member(urn=urn)
        retrieved_members = member.search_member(filter_params=['urn', 'first_name', 'last_name'])

        # If search returns member
        if retrieved_members != []:
            member = retrieved_members[0]
            member_attributes = {'first_name': member.first_name, 'last_name': member.last_name}

            form = UpdateMemberForm(initial=member_attributes)
```

And it works properly. But when I manually fill in the fields in the template, my view still sets those initial values. I cannot reset the values as the ones passed via POST method. I know this happens because of the way I set the initial values, but I don't know how I could fix it.

Does anyone has an idea of how I could solve this?

Comment: You need to check the POST data for the values and if they exist, update member_attributes accordingly before calling UpdateMemberForm()

Comment: @KRichardson, thanks for your advice. It helps a lot. Could you post ir as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Glad it helped! Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the POST data for values submitted, you can update member_attributes with those values before calling UpdateMemberForm()