# Django : Extract data from table to initially populate a form

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-views

I'm looking to initially populate my Django form with data based from another app. I followed this SO example in order to write my function :

[Initial populating on Django Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833403/initial-populating-on-django-forms)

However, I didn't succed to get what I want. This is what my function is supposed to do :

I have a model which is named : `Person` with lots of informations (firstname, ...) and a very useful `unique number` in order to distinguished each person.

Then, I have another model which is named `BirthCertificate` with a form in order to create a Birth Act. In my form view, user gives this `unique number` and Django is able to search the good person (not hard) et initially populate my form (which have some common fields between Person.model and BirthCertificate.model).

I have 2 steps :

- First : User writes person's unique number
- Second : User writes parents' unique number

I submit this informations and the first step should initially populate common fields. Second step works pretty well.

This is my function, but somethings still isn't working :

```
def BirthCertificate_Form_unique_number(request) :

    #User fill some fields
    query_social_number = request.GET.get('social_number')
    query_social_number_father = request.GET.get('social_number_father')
    query_social_number_mother = request.GET.get('social_number_mother')

    if query_social_number :
        query_social_number_list = Person.objects.filter(social_number=query_social_number)
        if query_social_number_list:
            sc_obj = query_social_number_list[0]
            #For example : sc_obj.lastname will extract lastname
            # etc ...

    else :
        query_social_number_list = Person.objects.none()

    initial_data = {
         'lastname': sc_obj.lastname, 
         'firstname': sc_obj.firstname, 
         'birthday': sc_obj.birthday, 
         'sex' : sc_obj.sex, 
         'birthcity': sc_obj.birthcity
         }

    form = BirthCertificateForm(request.POST or None, initial=initial_data)

    if form.is_valid() :   # Check data
        post = form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('BC_treated', kwargs={'id': post.id}))

    else:

        form = BirthCertificateForm()

        parent1 = Person.objects.filter(social_number=query_social_number_father)
        parent2 = Person.objects.filter(social_number=query_social_number_mother)

        form = BirthCertificateForm(request.POST or None)
        form.fields['fk_parent1'].queryset = parent1
        form.fields['fk_parent2'].queryset = parent2

    context = {
        "form" : form,
        "person" : person,
    }

    return render(request, 'BC_form2.html', context)
```

How can I re organise my part about `query_social_number` ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The reason for why it is not working is: `sc_obj` wont be present to populate the initial data when the `social_number` is not sent. Ideally it would have been raising exceptions "`sc_obj` is not defined".

You could have avoided this by putting it in a `try: except:` block and then printing/logging the stack trace.

Also you are re-populating the form if it is not valid. By doing that you are losing the errors part of the form.

Let me know if this works/ is this what you are expecting:

```
def BirthCertificate_Form_unique_number(request):
# User fill some fields
if request.method == 'GET':
    data = request.GET
    persons = Person.objects.filter(social_number=data.get('social_number', ''))
    if persons:
        sc_obj = persons.first()  # .latest()
        # For example : sc_obj.lastname will extract lastname
        # etc ...
        initial_data = {
            'lastname': sc_obj.lastname,
            'firstname': sc_obj.firstname,
            'birthday': sc_obj.birthday,
            'sex': sc_obj.sex,
            'birthcity': sc_obj.birthcity
        }
        form = BirthCertificateForm(initial=initial_data)
    else:
        query_social_number_father = request.GET.get('social_number_father')
        query_social_number_mother = request.GET.get('social_number_mother')
        form = BirthCertificateForm()
        parent1 = Person.objects.filter(social_number=query_social_number_father)
        parent2 = Person.objects.filter(social_number=query_social_number_mother)
        form.fields['fk_parent1'].queryset = parent1
        form.fields['fk_parent2'].queryset = parent2

elif request.method == 'POST':
    form = BirthCertificateForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():  # Check data
        post = form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('BC_treated', kwargs={'id': post.id}))

else:
    raise Exception("Method not allowed")


return render(request, 'BC_form2.html', {"form": form, "person": person})
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:**

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

@require_http_methods(["GET", "POST"]) # Allow only GET, POST methods
def BirthCertificate_Form_Unique_Number_View(request): #Add View in name for clarity
    # GET request case
    if request.method == "GET":
        data = request.GET
        sc_obj = Person.objects.get(social_number=data.get('social_number', ''))
        if sc_obj:
            initial_data = {
                'lastname': sc_obj.lastname,
                'firstname': sc_obj.firstname,
                'birthday': sc_obj.birthday,
                'sex': sc_obj.sex,
                'birthcity': sc_obj.birthcity
            }
            form = BirthCertificateForm(initial=initial_data)
        else:
            query_social_number_father = data.get('social_number_father')
            query_social_number_mother = data.get('social_number_mother')
            form = BirthCertificateForm()
            parent1 = Person.objects.get(social_number=query_social_number_father)
            parent2 = Person.objects.get(social_number=query_social_number_mother)
            form.fields['fk_parent1'] = parent1
            form.fields['fk_parent2'] = parent2
    # POST request case
    elif request.method == "POST":
        form = BirthCertificateForm(request.POST)
        # Assuming this works as intended 
        if form.is_valid():  # Check data
            post = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('BC_treated', kwargs={'id': post.id}))

    context = {
        "form" : form,
        "person" : person,
    }

    return render(request, 'BC_form2.html', context)
```

---

Your method as presented, was trying to fill the form without waiting the `social_number` data from the request. For that reason it defaulted to the `else` part of your code.

You are trying to get just one object from the Person model because the ID is unique. That means, that a Person exists and is unique or does not exist at all. The above mentioned, you don't need to filter your queryset, but to retrieve just one entry (if exists) and that is done with `Person.objects.get(...)`.

With the usage of the `@require_http_methods(["GET", "POST"])` decorator you allow only GET and POST requests to your view and you must check for those 2 in your code. Essentially you are limiting your cases to only two, for the rest the service will respond: `Method not allowed`.

Comment: Hey, @Deadpool I was passing through my answers. Did you find this answer helpful? Care to accept?