# Pass user's primary key (pk) from previous page to current page

Tags: django

I'm building a review page, where an annoymous user leaves a review on a user's page (my user is called Agent).  The `Review` model has an `agent` field, specifying a ForeignKey relationship with Agent.

**urls**

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/review/$', views.leave_review, name='leave_review'),
```

**HTML code to get to the leave_review page:**

```
<form action="{% url 'leave_review' pk=agent.pk %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button class="button3"><span>Leave review</span></button>
</form>
```

**Leave review views.py**

```
def leave_review(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = ReviewForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.agent = Agent.objects.get(pk=pk)
            form.save()
            return redirect('review_success.html')
    else:
        form = ReviewForm()

    return render(request, 'leave_review.html', {'form': form})
```

**models.py**

```
class Review(models.Model):
    # ... Other fields

    agent = models.ForeignKey(Agent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.agent is None:  # Set default reference
            self.agent = Agent.objects.get(id=1)
        super(Review, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I'm currently getting a ValueError, `Cannot assign "''": "Review.agent" must be a "Agent" instance.`  I believe I specified the 'pk' correctly in this case,but it is not being picked up.  What's wrong here?

**Full trackback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/agents/2/review/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=CIxNqtEaFjFIfVwmB6SyV2SAF1VuiDgEf3Di7qZoucG4thIn9ixCbe7GO2UuuW85

Django Version: 1.11.5
Python Version: 3.6.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'bungol.accounts',
 'bungol.databases',
 'bungol.coresite',
 'bungol.listings',
 'django_extensions',
 'djstripe']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Python 3.6.2 (32bit)\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Python 3.6.2 (32bit)\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python 3.6.2 (32bit)\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Valachio\Google Drive\Bungol\bungolv4\bungol\databases\views.py" in leave_review
  69.         if form.is_valid():

File "C:\Python 3.6.2 (32bit)\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in is_valid
  183.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "C:\Python 3.6.2 (32bit)\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in errors
  175.             self.full_clean()

File "C:\Python 3.6.2 (32bit)\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in full_clean
  386.         self._post_clean()

File "C:\Python 3.6.2 (32bit)\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in _post_clean
  408.             self.instance = construct_instance(self, self.instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)

File "C:\Python 3.6.2 (32bit)\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in construct_instance
  65.             f.save_form_data(instance, cleaned_data[f.name])

File "C:\Python 3.6.2 (32bit)\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in save_form_data
  853.         setattr(instance, self.name, data)

File "C:\Python 3.6.2 (32bit)\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __set__
  216.                     self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,

Exception Type: ValueError at /agents/2/review/
Exception Value: Cannot assign "''": "Review.agent" must be a "Agent" instance.
```

---

```
class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):

    REVIEWER_TYPE = (
        # ... some choices
    )

    LOCATION = (
        # ... some choices
    )

    STARS = (
        # ... some choices
    )

    reviewer_type = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=REVIEWER_TYPE)
    property_type = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=BuyerListing.PROPERTY_TYPE)
    number_of_bedrooms = forms.ChoiceField(choices=BuyerListing.BEDS_OPTION)
    location = forms.ChoiceField(choices=LOCATION)
    stars = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=STARS)
    agent = forms.ChoiceField(widget = forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ['agent', 'reviewer_first_name', 'reviewer_last_name', 'reviewer_email', 'reviewer_type', 'transaction_id', 'location', 'property_type', 'number_of_bedrooms', 'stars', 'content']
```

Comment: This code shouldn't give that error. Please show the full traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Added to original post

Comment: I'm sorry, this really can't be the actual code. The HTML form contains no fields, so the Django form would never be valid and `form.save()` wouldn't even be reached.

Comment: @DanielRoseman My mistake.  The form's method was `post`, so it was automatically jumping to the post processing part of the view.

I changed it to `get`, which allowed me to fill out the form.  After filling out the form, I still got the same error.  I updated the traceback.

Comment: Can you also add the code of your `ReviewForm` please ?

Comment: @ClémentDenoix Added

Comment: @Valachio Thank you, I understand better now. Added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This line in the view is useless:

```
form.agent = Agent.objects.get(pk=pk)
```

A form instance is not like a django model, you cannot set a field attribute like this. To do so, you got two solutions:

1. You could get the object from the form first, set the agent and save the object afterward. So remove the `agent` field from your form, and make your code in the view like this:

   ```
   def leave_review(request, pk):
       if request.method == 'POST':

           form = ReviewForm(request.POST)

           if form.is_valid():
               review = form.save(commit=False)  # Getting the unsaved `Review` instance from the form
               review.agent = Agent.objects.get(pk=pk)  # Set the agent on the `Review` instance
               review.save()  # Finally save the `Review` instance

               return redirect('review_success.html')
           else:
               form = ReviewForm()

       return render(request, 'leave_review.html', {'form': form})
   ```

   [Documentation about the save method in the Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)
2. If you really need to have this `agent` field in your form (But as it is a hidden field, I assume you don't ?) you could pass the value from the form `initial` keyword, like stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833403/initial-populating-on-django-forms) ([Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values)):

   ```
   def leave_review(request, pk):
       if request.method == 'POST':

           # Passing initial data to the form so our `agent` field will be populated
           data = {'agent': Agent.objects.get(pk=pk)}
           form = ReviewForm(request.POST, initial=data)

           if form.is_valid():
               review.save()

               return redirect('review_success.html')
           else:
               form = ReviewForm()

       return render(request, 'leave_review.html', {'form': form})
   ```