# Django modify blank form field sent to template

Tags: django, django-forms

Here I am again with my daft questions..
I'm creating a blank form but just want the Username field to be filled automatically. should be simple, right?

views.py

```
#blank form wswEditUser is the form model in forms.py
form = wswEditUser()
form.fields["Username"].value = someuser
return render(request, 'wswEdit.html', {'form': form })
```

but instead, the Username input box on the form is still blank
am i stupid ?

Comment: You can use `initials`, so `wswEditUser(initials={'Username': someuser})`.

Comment: Can someone flag this as a potential duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833403/initial-populating-on-django-forms

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem - thanks - that's exactly what i was looking for.
slight typo in your answer 'initials=' should be 'initial='
Can you post this as an answer and i'll mark it as accepted

Comment: @Janvier, although this question has the same solution as the one you suggested as a dupe, I've been searching for an hour and would only find the existing answer if i knew to search for the word 'initial' (which of course, is the answer, not the queston :-)