# Get username in Django Forms

Tags: python, django

I want to get username in my form. For example: username of current user is admin then in my form, the name part should fill with '*admin*' automatically. What should I do?
Here is my codes...

**views.py**

```
def attendanceView(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = AttendanceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            attendance = AttendanceModel()
            attendance.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            attendance.date = form.cleaned_data['date']
            attendance.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = AttendanceForm()
    return render(request, 'attendance.html', {'form': form})
```

**models.py**

```
class AttendanceModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'date',)
```

**forms.py**

```
class AttendanceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AttendanceModel
        fields=('name', 'date')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initial populating on Django Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833403/initial-populating-on-django-forms)

Answer (score 1):

You can prepopulate specific fields of the form in your view.

**views.py**

```
   def attendanceView(request):
      if request.method=='POST':
          form = AttendanceForm(request.POST)
          if form.is_valid():
              attendance = AttendanceModel()
              attendance.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
              attendance.date = form.cleaned_data['date']
              attendance.save()
              return redirect('home')
          else:
              initial = {'name':request.user.username}
              form = AttendanceForm(initial=intial)
      return render(request, 'attendance.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prepopulate parts of the form with the `initial` keyword argument: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial.

In your case, this would be something like this in the `else` clause: `form = AttendanceForm(initial={"username": request.user.username})`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the the user from **init** method in the forms.py.
First instantiate the user in the view.

```
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = AttendanceForm(request.POST, name=request.name)
        if form.is_valid():
            attendance = AttendanceModel()
            attendance.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            attendance.date = form.cleaned_data['date']
            attendance.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = AttendanceForm(name=request.name)
    return render(request, 'attendance.html', {'form': form})
```

Then in the forms you need to add an __init_ method.

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = kwargs.pop('name')
        super(AttendanceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        name = forms.CharField()

        if name is not None:
            self.fields['name'] = forms.CharField(initial=self.name)
```