# How to autofill editable forms in Django

Tags: python, django

tl;dr How to autofill an editable form with information stored in database

Hey, Im creating a profile page for an application using Django as a framework. And Im having some annoying issues when a user is editing their page. As it is now, the user has to retype every field in the form, to edit a single field.. Cause my view has to delete the previous information in each field, or I get some annoying errors.

So my question is, is there a way to autofill these fields in profile_edit.html with the strings corresponding to each field in the form, from the database?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :D

view.py

```
@login_required
def profile_edit(request):
form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

if request.method == 'POST':

    if form.is_valid():
        user = request.user
        if 'image' in request.FILES:

            user.profile.image = request.FILES['image']
        user.profile.bio = form.cleaned_data.get("bio")
        user.profile.birth_date = form.cleaned_data.get("birth_date")
        user.profile.location = form.cleaned_data.get("location")
        user.save()
        return redirect('profile')
    else:
        form = ProfileUpdateForm()

context = {
    'form' : form

}
return render(request, 'webside/profile_edit.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    image= models.FileField(upload_to='profile_image/', blank = True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

profile_edit.html

```
'{% csrf_token %}
          {% for field in form %}
            <p>
              {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
              {{ field }}

              {% for error in field.errors %}
                <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
              {% endfor %}
            </p>
          {% endfor %}'
```

[pic of profile.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PAsw.png)
forms.py

```
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
YEARS= [x for x in range(1900,2021)]
birth_date = forms.DateField( initial="21-06-1995", widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=YEARS))
class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ('bio','birth_date','location','image')
```

Comment: Also, my DatField( initial ) attribute wont work, any obvious reason to why? :)

Comment: You can find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833403/initial-populating-on-django-forms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you initialise your form in your view is all wrong:

```
def profile_edit(request):
    user = request.user
    # form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES) <-- remove

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user.profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()  # <-- you can just save the form, it will save the profile
            # user.save()  <-- this doesn't help you, it doesn't save the profile and since user isn't changed you don't need to save it!
            return redirect(...)
        # else:
        #    form = ProfileUpdateForm()  <-- don't clear the form!

    else:  # GET
        form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=user.profile) <-- initialise with instance

    context = {
        'form' : form
    }
    return render(request, 'webside/profile_edit.html', context)
```

You need to add the `instance` to the form to update an existing instance. You shouldn't initialise an empty form if the form is not valid, because that means the user loses all the data if they made a mistake. You want to display the form with all the data and the errors in that case.