# How to auto-populate a form from database in Django?

Tags: django, database, django-forms

I have two forms, and I want to auto fill the second form depending on one field of the first form. How can I do that ? Do I have to override some methods ?

Tournament Form

```
class MyModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.name

class TournamentCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    name                = forms.CharField(label='Name', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                    'class':'form-control',
                                    'placeholder': 'Enter the name of the tournament'}))
    dateStart           = forms.DateField(label='Beginning', widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={
                                    'class':'form-control',
                                    'placeholder': 'Enter the date of the beginning'}))
    dateEnd             = forms.DateField(label='Ending', widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={
                                    'class':'form-control',
                                    'placeholder': 'Enter the date of the end'}))
    nbMaxTeam           = forms.IntegerField(label='Number max of team', widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={
                                    'class':'form-control',
                                    'placeholder':'Max 24'}))
    nameGymnasium       = forms.CharField(label='Name of the gymnasium', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                    'class':'form-control',
                                    'placeholder': 'Enter the name of the gymnasium'}))
    addressGymnasium    = forms.CharField(label='Address of the gymnasium', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                    'class':'form-control',
                                    'placeholder': 'Enter the address of the gymnasium'}))
    sport               = MyModelChoiceField(queryset=Sport.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={
                                    'class':'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model   = Tournament
        fields  = [
            'name',
            'dateStart',
            'dateEnd',
            'nbMaxTeam',
            'nameGymnasium',
            'addressGymnasium',
            'sport'
        ]
```

Sport Form

```
class SportEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    timeMatch           = forms.DecimalField(label='Time for one match', widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={
                                    'class':'form-control',
                                    'placeholder':'Enter the the time for one match',
                                    'step': 0.1}))
    nbpointpervictory   = forms.IntegerField(label='Points per Victory', widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={
                                    'class':'form-control',
                                    'placeholder':'Enter the points for a victory'}))
    nbpointperdefeat    = forms.IntegerField(label='Points per Defeat', widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={
                                    'class':'form-control',
                                    'placeholder':'Enter the points for a defeat'}))
    nbpointperdraw      = forms.IntegerField(label='Points per Draw', widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={
                                    'class':'form-control',
                                    'placeholder':'Enter the points for a draw'}))
    nbset               = forms.IntegerField(label='Numebr of sets', widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={
                                    'class':'form-control',
                                    'placeholder':'Enter the number of sets'}))
    nbpointperset       = forms.IntegerField(label='Points per set', widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={
                                    'class':'form-control',
                                    'placeholder':'Enter the number of points for one set'}))
    class Meta:
        model   = Sport
        fields  = [
            'timeMatch',
            'nbpointpervictory',
            'nbpointperdefeat',
            'nbpointperdraw',
            'nbset',
            'nbpointperset'
        ]
```

I have also two forms. In my tournament form, I have to select the sport of the tournament. At this point it's ok, but I'd like to update my fields of my sport_form depending on the sport selected.

Here is my view:

```
def tournament_creation_view(request, *args, **kwargs): #*args, **kwargs
    form_tournament = TournamentCreationForm(request.POST or None)
    form_sport      = SportEditForm(request.POST or None)
    if form_tournament.is_valid() and form_sport.is_valid():
        instance = form_tournament.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.save()

    context = {
        'form_tournament': form_tournament,
        'form_sport': form_sport
    }
    return render(request, "tournament_creation.html", context)
```

I think I have to override a method but what method and where ? In my tournament form, I have this field named "sport", it lists all sport that I already saved in DB. When I select one I'd like to auto fill fields of sport form.

EDIT :

"sport" is a field of tournament form. It's a ModelChoiceField that lists all the sport that are already saved in the DB. I'd like to make this: when I select one sport, my other form (sport form) fill up automatically with the data that are already exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initial populating on Django Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833403/initial-populating-on-django-forms)

Comment: This is not what I look for I think. I want to fill my fields depending on a field of an other form. When I select a Sport in my "sport" field of my tournament form, I want to fill the fields of the orther form.

Comment: You would in essence have to do the same. But you need two views and use an AJAX query to reload the second form if they are both on one HTML page.

Comment: I want to use only one view. How can I do that ?