# How to populate django form with selection from your models

Tags: django

I have a CreateSong CBV in Django that allows me to create song objects to a model. My question is, in the form I created for the view, how do I make the album column to be auto-populated with albums the user-created only? I get errors calling "self" that way.

See my views below

```
  class CreateSong(CreateView):
    model = Song
    fields = [album, song_title]
    fields['album'].queryset = Album.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initial populating on Django Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833403/initial-populating-on-django-forms)

Comment: I have the comments there but there's nothing helpful. I just want to see the only albums related to that user.

Comment: I have made some corrections to the code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should override `get_form`. See the example below:

```
class CreateSong(CreateView):
    model = Song
    fields = [album, song_title]

    def get_form(self):
        form = super().get_form()
        form.fields['album'].queryset = Album.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
        return form
```

Comment: Thank you. As at when i asked this question, i didn't have enough reputation to comment or actually upvote. Now i have, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have access to `self.request.user`, because you are calling it at class level, thus when the class is being defined and not when the view is actually called. Instead you should override the `get_form` method as in Davit's answer.